# Como preencher um TextBox e fazer raspagem de dados com Python?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Estou tentando analisar alguns dados da secretário da educação. Já fiz a requisição, mas...
Achei um jeito de fazer isso pela web mesmo, no entanto, são muitas escolas por esse motivo preciso automatizar alguns passos.[image: Imagem do formulário a ser preenchido]

Na imagem podemos ver o campo "Escola", tenho esses nomes em um *.CSV preciso pegar nome por nome preencher esse campo e "pegar" o número CIE da escola ou "linkar" nele. Tudo isso em Python, tem como?

Comment: Você pode fazer tudo isso com o Python sim. Utilizando a biblioteca csv para manipular os dados do csv, e requests para enviar os POST's e manipular as informações que a pagina vai te devolver. Mas fica muito complicado responder a pergunta feita no titulo sem a apresentação de nenhum código.

Comment: Não sabia por onde começar. Vou estudar sobre a biblioteca CSV e requests e e começar o código.